# I want to scroll relative layout as well also want to drag imageview which is in relative layout but button doesn't drag in scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my **xml** layout is here

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/vg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Above is my Xml Layout  with scroll bar
when I remove this scroll bar then imageview move
**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.wordcombat1;


import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.Status;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private View selected_item = null;
    private int offset_x = 0;
    private int offset_y = 0;
    int status = 0;
    int windowwidth,windowheight;
    ImageView tv1;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.vg);
        windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();


        tv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
        tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
            switch(event.getActionMasked())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                    if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                        x_cord = windowwidth;
                    }
                    if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                        y_cord = windowheight;
                    }
                    layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                    layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                    tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        });
    }

}
```

Can anybody help me how both things can be move.
Relative layout also scroll as well imageview also drag properly.
without scroll bar imageview move well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Grid View instead the scroll view i think your problem solved